# I am receiving notifications my Facebook app does not meet requirements

Tags: facebook

My Facebook App is violating Platform Terms 4.b. I have searched how to fix this with no luck. Do you have any insight?

Comment: Should be referring to your privacy policy, https://developers.facebook.com/terms/dfc_platform_terms/#privacypolicy: _"b. This policy must comply with applicable law and regulations and must accurately and clearly explain what data you are Processing, how you are Processing it, the purposes for which you are Processing it, and how Users may request deletion of that data."_

Comment: Can you tell me what my policy must say to make it compliant?

Comment: No, I can not. First of all, that is a _legal_ question, and not a programming one - so it does not really belong here in the first place. And second, what kind of processing of what kind of data your app does in detail, no one here but you knows at this point.